Doctrine Query builder search JSONB
I would like search JSONB column using query builder
If I do this SQL command in DBeaver it works
SELECT id, location
FROM post
WHERE location->>'title' LIKE '%test%'

but it does not work using query builder
I have this basic query:
  public function testsql(): void
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        $qb = $qb->select('a.id', 'a.location');
        $qb = $qb->andWhere("a.location->>'title' LIKE :loc0");
        $qb = $qb->setParameter('loc0', ' %test% ');

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $result = $query->getResult();
    }

I get error:

In QueryException.php line 23:
                                                                   
  [Syntax Error] line 0, col 64: Error: Expected Literal, got '>'  
                                                                   

In QueryException.php line 18:
                                                                                        
  SELECT a.id, a.location FROM App\Entity\Post a WHERE a.location->>'title' LIKE :loc0  


Is there a single reason to use query builder's exorcism instead of the native query once that you have it written and tested?

yes, I build my query dynamically

Generating text dynamically is not at all a reason to use a query builder that uses imperative language/syntax to express declarative logic. This is proprietary, cryptic and smudgy rather than standard, clear and easy to read as native SQL is.
